# How to find two NSArray has common NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, search

I have an NSArray. It has one or more NSDictionary. `otherContacts` has one dictionary in each index. `chatContacts` has two dictionary in each index. How can i find both `Array` has same `contact_detail`.

```
NSArray * otherContacts = {
        "contact_detail" =         {
          "contact_Label" = "Test 5 ";
           userid = 48;
        };
   }

NSArray * chatContacts ={
        "contact_detail" =         {
          "contact_Label" = "Test 5 ";
          userid = 48;
        };
        "last_msg_details" =     {
         "Key_from_me" = 1;
         data = " B";
        };
   }
```

I have tried like this using NSPredicate. But Its not returning the common data.

```
NSArray *filtered = [otherContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [chatContacts containsObject:evaluatedObject];
    }]];
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `NSMutableSet` to accomplish that:

Like,

```
NSMutableSet* set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
NSMutableSet* set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array2];

//Find intersect: Which will give common objects
[set1 intersectSet:set2]; 

//Array with common objects
NSArray* arrCommon = [set1 allObjects];

//Now check common objects count to find if it has common object

if(arrCommon.count>0){

  //has common dictionary
}
```